# Spring Web Flow - Multiple forms on page - validating correct form

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I am using Spring Web Flow 2.3 and I have a page that has two forms on it that transition to different places depending on which is submitted. To accomplish this, I have one composite model object for my view-state that holds the two forms inside. The problem I am seeing is that if transition A is fired, I only want to validate form A, and likewise with form B - only want to validate B if B transition fired. I am not sure how to indicate which form to validate. View state that is validating the entire compositeForm for each transition:

```
<view-state model="compositeForm">
    <transition on="formAsubmit" to="formApage" validate="true"/>
    <transition on="formBsubmit" to="formBpage" validate="true"/>
</view-state>
```

Does anyone know how I can trigger a custom validator to validate differently depending on which transition was fired?

Thanks for you help.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to manually trigger my validation when form B was submitted and transition to a decision-state that checks if there were validation errors. It's a little ugly, but I feel like it's the best way:

```
<view-state id="start" model="compositeForm">
    <transition on="formAsubmit" to="pageA" validate="true"/>
    <transition on="formBsubmit" to="isFormBValid" validate="false">
        <evaluate expression="formBValidator.validate(compositeForm.formB, messageContext)"/>
    </transition
</view-state>

<decision-state id="isFormBValid">
    <if test="messageContext.hasErrorMessages()" then="start" else="pageB"/>
</decision-state>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about a custom validator for each, but within your validation method, I think you could use the [`RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContextHolder.html#getRequestContext--) to [`getCurrentTransition()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContext.html#getCurrentTransition--) or [`getCurrentEvent()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContext.html#getCurrentEvent--) and compare manually to the `getId()` value.

Comment: Good idea dbreaux. Unfortunately, I tried it, and `getCurrentTransition()` is returning `null` in my validator. The validator is automatically triggered by a transition, so I expected `getCurrentTransition` to work.

Comment: Did you try some of the other methods? Like getCurrentEvent()?

Comment: @dbreaux, yes `getCurrentEvent().getAttributes()` returns a map of all of the request attributes, which will include the `_eventId` parameter, so I guess that could have worked. Have to be careful because eg. 'submit' event can be triggered by either attribute: `_eventId=submit` or `_eventId_submit=''`, so would have to parse that carefully. +1 for the great ideas. I think I lean toward my solution though, because it doesn't resort to looking at and parsing request attributes.

Comment: I meant `getCurrentEvent().getId()`. Just the simple transition name there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but at least is solves the problem. This is how I obtained my transition id and view-state id in vlaidator.

Transition id

```
RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getFlowExecutionContext().getActiveSession().getState().getId();
```

view-state id

```
 RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getFlowExecutionContext().getActiveSession().getState().getId();
```